# Reduction of Order in Homogeneous Linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I was trying to solve this exercise,
$yy''=3(y')^2$
The question asks to reduce the ODE to first-order before proceeding to solve the equation. For your information, I am still in Homogeneous Linear ODE and I find it hard to find the solution. So I decided to check the solution on Slader (Quizlet + now).
However, it creates more confusion. This is the first part of the solution in Slader.

$z'=\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}(z(y))=\frac{dz}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=z'\cdot y'$

Assuming $z=y’$.

I couldn't wrap my head around this part.
$\frac{d}{dx}(z(y))$
It is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You could directly separate to get logarithmic derivatives
$$
\frac{y''}{y'}=3\frac{y'}{y}.
$$

The trick that is proposed to you works better backwards, assume that $y$ is in bijection with $x$ so that the free parameter can be changed, so that $y'(x)=z(y(x))$. Now apply the chain rule for the second derivative, $y''(x)=z'(y(x))y'(x)=z'(y)z(y)$. If you insert that you get
$$
z'(y)z(y)y=3z(y)^2\implies z(y)·(z'(y)y-3z(y))=0.
$$
As the segments under consideration have $z(y)=y'\ne 0$, one can extract the second factor and solve